# Google Appengine: programmatic access to request log files?

Tags: google-app-engine

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

> An app can read files, but only files uploaded with the application code.

I am assuming this precludes one from programmatically reading the request log files - is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of logs: HTTP request logs and the entries that are stored to the App Engine logger. As Dmitry mentions, it is possible to retrieve the HTTP request logs via appcfg.py, however, there's currently no interface for retrieving logs programmatically.

It'll be a good idea to add the enhancements to this issue in the issue tracker and star it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=76

**Edit because people are still commenting on this issue 3+ years later.** There's been an update. There's now a [Logs API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/) that allows some of what you might be looking for.

Comment: appcfg.py does it kinda programmatically, you may see the source code on the link. It uses an HTTP request, though.

Comment: appcfg.py fetches the request logs - not the logs that are stored in the log viewer.

Comment: this implies you can ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455402/downloading-detailed-logs-from-google-app-engine

Answer (score 3):

now is possible

```
The Logs API provides access to the application and request 
logs for your application.
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/overview

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but I believe that one can issue an HTTP request and get the logs, [like appcfg.py does](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py&q=appcfg.py&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc&l=772)