# Downloading detailed logs from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I want to download the raw access logs from google app engine app written in python.

I have tried following commands:

```
appcfg.py request_logs --num_days=2 . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_29march.log
```

Gives me 47943 records.
But the records does have only header in http clf format. {Here i need to get the detailed log for each record, but i get only headers}

But if i use

```
appcfg.py --severity=0 --num_days=2 request_logs . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_27March.log
appcfg.py --severity=1 --num_days=2 --append request_logs . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_27March.log
appcfg.py --severity=2 --num_days=2 --append request_logs . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_27March.log
appcfg.py --severity=3 --num_days=2 --append request_logs . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_27March.log
appcfg.py --severity=4 --num_days=2 --append request_logs . ~/Documents/workspace/loganalyzer/applog_27March.log
```

I get a total of only 2000 records with detailed errors also.

In my opinion they should match to 47943 records.

Comment: Pass --severity when downloading logs. Answered in SO here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229293/download-log-from-appengine-including-python-log-statements

Answer (score 4):

App Engine uses circular buffers for the different levels of logs - one for each severity level. When it runs out of space, it overwrites the oldest log entries. As a result, your error logs will go back further than your warning logs, which will go further than info logs, and so forth - and ordinary HTTP request logs will be kept the longest.

Comment: But then how am i able to view them in the google app engine log viewer?

Comment: @androidexp Are you? How did you determine how many error/debug/etc log entries there are in the viewer?

Comment: I think question is asking for "detailed logs". The appcfg tool can only be used to download basic request details e.g client-ip, url/query/path, http-status. In the viewer you can see all log msgs emitted by the app in addition

Comment: @srinivas1729 No, the command line above allows you to download log messages from the app, not just HTTP logs.